# Is it Possible to Filter Graph Feed using Location?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

We have a worldwide brand page that posts brand messages and filtered by country, for example: "This is visible in the US" (visible to United States), and "This is visible to Russia" (only visible to Russia).

Main Question: Is it possible to retrieve posts on the page wall filtered by country or other location parameters? For example: https://graph.facebook.com/[userID]/feed?access_token=[accessToken]&locale=en_US

Side Question: Currently when using the URL above (without &locale...) returns only the posts available worldwide, and all targeted posts are not returned. This could potentially be due to the access token being used as I am able to return info for page feeds (that I own) for all locales using a different access token. Is there a correlation between application tokens and locales that are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about it - **it's impossible**. They never thought about providing us any interface to this.

What you must do is:

1. **Download** the entire graph object (awesome especially on mobile),
2. Remember to download **all pages** (since facebook is paging long responses),
3. **Merge** and **filter** them on your side (or in client's browser|phone),
4. **Voilà** you're good to go ;) .

PS. I know you asked this looong time ago, but it's still one of the first Google results for related queries, so I'm writing here so others can quickly find out. Cheers!